.NET 8.0 : there was an error running the selected code generator: 'Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Learn."
I were doing this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/movie-database-app/part-2?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=vs.
When I add Razor components using Entity Framework (CRUD):


After I press add, it throws an error

There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Learn."

In this tutorial, till that step, it's not require install any package.
Please help me!

It might be worth mentioning which specific version of VS2022 you're using. Minor version (17.6, 17.7 etc) updates to VS are pretty substantial. Same with the .NET SDK.

This is always resulted from nuget package version conflict. Anyway, I had a test in my side with VS 2022 and create a new .Net 8 blazor web app and following the tutorial(I trust you are referring to this tutorial) to do the scaffolding, it worked well. Before scaffolding, there's no nuget packages in this new project(no  section), but after the scaffolding, the following nuget packages appear in my project file and my csproj file will look like below.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid.EntityFrameworkAdapter" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.8">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="8.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Please double click the project name in your VS and you will open the csproj file, then you can see whether there's any PackageReference there. If not, you might copy and paste above items into your file and press "Ctrl + Shift + B" to build your application and see whether there's any error in the output window.
Normally speaking, if you are using .Net 8 and is using latest nuget packages, you won't get that error. So that please make sure you are having a new blazor web app .net 8 app and it can run successfully, then try to do the scaffolding.
